# How to make the column names of a data-frame variables

Tags: r, dataframe

I can construct a `data.frame` like this -

```
data.frame('a_1' = 3)
```

However, I want to make the column-name `a1` as variable. So I tried this -

```
data.frame(get(paste("a", 1, sep = "_")) = 3)
```

With this I get below error -

```
Error: unexpected '=' in "data.frame(get(paste("a", 1, sep = "_")) ="
```

Can you please help me to understand the right approach to make the `colnames` as variable?

Thanks for your pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `tibble` with `:=` to do this

```
library(stringr)
library(tibble)
tibble(!! str_c("a", "_", 1) := 3)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 1 x 1
    a_1
  <dbl>
1     3
```

---

In `base R`, this can be done using `setNames`

```
df1 <- setNames(data.frame(3), paste0("a", "_", 1))
```

-output

```
df1
   a_1
1   3
```

---

Or if it is only for a specific number of columns, create the dataset, and use `names`

```
df1 <- data.frame(3)
names(df1)[1] <- paste0("a_", 1)
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to use `setNames` function to replace a specific column name leaving all other column-names as-is

Comment: @BrianSmith that is possible with `data.table::setnames` though.  With `setNames` you have to specify all the colums.  or use `names(df1)[1] <- paste0("a", "_", 1)`